# Java trie node Boolean vs boolean

Tags: java, boolean

I'm creating trie node class, which contains field with logical type and I don't know what will be better use boolean or Boolean.

I know that one instance of Boolean takes 16 Bytes and 4 bytes takes it reference in 32-bit VM. But Boolean have constants Boolean.TRUE and Boolean.FALSE, what can be used for space optimization. So application wiil takes 4*N+32 Bytes, where N is number of nodes, yes?

As far, as I know boolean value takes 4 bytes (in array it optimize to 1 byte per element) in 32-bit VM too)

However I can use code like this

```
boolean EOW = Boolean.TRUE;
```

but how many space it will take and how many time wiil take autboxing/inboxing?

So what will be better to use to optimize space usage and time?
And could you answer me how many space it tales on 64-bit VM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
boolean EOW = Boolean.TRUE;
```

Just write this:

```
boolean EOW = true;
```

There is no reason to use `Boolean.TRUE`, it will be auto-unboxed to the primitive value `true` anyway, it's more efficient and less verbose to use the value `true` directly.

Only use wrapper classes such as `Boolean` when you have a good reason to do so - otherwise, use primitive types such as `boolean`. One reason to use a wrapper is when you need to store values in a collection (such as an `ArrayList`) - collection classes can only hold objects and not primitive values, so you'll have to use the wrapper class in that case.

Using `Boolean` objects is never more efficient than using `boolean` primitive values.

Note that primitive values are just *values*, not objects. If you use the value `true` ten times in your code, there will not be ten duplicate objects in memory.

Comment: eah, I know about collections, because of generics structure.
I known that use primitives better then wrappers, but I was not sure about Boolean

Comment: So you mean that values like `true` and `false` are something like cashing?

Comment: according to your post I can do conclusion that this all will take 
`N*sizeOfReferences + 8` bytes?

Comment: @MichaelH. Values like `true` and `false` are just primitive values, just like primitive integer values, for example (0, 1, 2, 3, ...). It doesn't have anything to do with caching.

Comment: @MichaelH. On Oracle's JVM I guess a `boolean` would take up 4 bytes. A `Boolean` variable is a reference to a `Boolean` object - the reference itself would be 4 bytes, and the object it refers to would take up some memory, for example 16 bytes. Far more than a primitive `boolean`.

Comment: @MichaelH. Note that variables of primitive types directly contain a value, whereas variables of non-primitive types don't directly contain a value - they just contain a reference (a pointer) to the place in memory where the object is stored that holds the actual value.

Comment: em, I heared the same things 
so every `boolean` variable will take 4 bytes even when I create 10 `boolean` variables with `true` value?

Comment: @MichaelH. every variable needs space to store its value, so ofcourse it will take 10 times 4 bytes when you have 10 variables.

Comment: aha, so object reference is 4 Bytes and non-objects is just values

Comment: thanks for good explanation, you are an awesome guy)
have a nice day

Answer (score 3):

Just use the primitive type `boolean` with `true` and `false`. Primitive types take less memory, work with better performance and are null-safe.

Answer (score 0):

I expect the exact code, that you pasted, to be optimized to `boolean EOW = true;`, so it shouldn't be unboxed at all, but if there's no such an optimization, then you'll haven't any memory affected, because you use the static field, which will be initialized only once. Nevertheless, you still will lose one operation on imlicit running method `booleanValue()`, which will just return stored value. Actually, I don't have any idea, why you would want to have such an expression.